# How to get an 'array of strings' as a function's return type?

Tags: c++, function, return-type

String[] decode(String message)

Above is an example. I need to get 2 strings s1 and s2 as the return values for the decode function. How should I proceed?

Comment: std::vector<std::string> decode(std::string message);

Answer (score 6):

If you need return few strings, use one of next:
- std::pair
- boost::tuple
- structure

If you don't know how many strings your function will return - use something like std::vector.

Comment: Soon, it will be std::tuple, not boost::tuple :-)

Answer (score 4):

If it were me, I'd return a `vector` of `string`s.  With an array, you'll need to worry about memory management.  You could also pass the string in as a const reference, if you don't want to modify it.

Comment: I got it from the Top Coder practice sessions. It's been asked in the question to return an array of strings.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the options are:

For a fixed number of strings:

1) return a pair, a tuple, or a struct that you define yourself. Something like:

```
struct BrokenDownString {
    std::string firstbit;
    std::string middlebit;
    std::string endbit;
};
```

Then either:

```
BrokenDownString decode(std::string message);
```

or just give BrokenDownString a constructor taking the message as a parameter.

2) Take multiple out params by pointer or non-constant reference:

```
void decode(const std::string &message, std::string &out_1, std::string &out_2) {
    out_1 = /*whatever*/;
    out_2 = /*whatever*/;
}
```

For two strings, anything else (even an array) is overkill.

For a variable number of strings, however, you can either:

1) return a `std::vector<std::string>` (be aware that this may result in excess copying).

2) take a `std::vector<std::string> &` as a parameter, and append the results (this may copy strings but not the container).

3) make decode a function template, taking an output iterator as a parameter:

```
template<typename OUT>
void decode(const std::string message, OUT out) {
    // do parsing
    *(out++) = firstbit;
    *(out++) = nextbit;
    // etc.
}
```

Then if the caller wants the results in a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
decode(message, std::back_inserter(v));
```

If the caller prefers them in a deque:

```
std::deque<std::string> d;
decode(message, std::back_inserter(d));
```

If the caller wants them in a list in reverse order:

```
std::list<std::string> l;
decode(message, std::front_inserter(l));
```

And so on.

4) If you want something like the above, but for whatever reason you don't want to write template code, make decode take as a parameter an object, which it notifies of each string:

```
struct DecodeTarget {
    virtual void append(const std::string &) = 0;
};

void decode(std::string message, DecodeTarget &out) {
    // do parsing
    out.append(firstbit);
    out.append(nextbit);
    // etc.
}
```

Then if the caller wants the results in a vector:

```
class VectorTarget : public DecodeTarget {
private:
    std::vector<std::string> &results;
public:
    VectorTarget(std::vector<std::string> &v) : results(v) { }
    void append(const std::string &bit) { v.push_back(bit); }
};

std::vector<std::string> v;
VectorTarget vt(v);
decode(message, vt);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling hardcore and up for the challenge, you could return a char**.

However, this is very error prone, so you should probably stick to a standard container or string class instead.

Comment: @siddhant3s: He means a char**, just like argv in main. Use a NULL terminator, and this is the old fashioned c way of doing thing. You should treat this approach as deprecated in c++, but it *will* work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did they(Top Coder) mentioned array of C-strings or array of std::strings ?
For your information, arrays are evil (http://siddhant3s.googlepages.com/how_to_tell_rusted_cpp.html and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.1)
Lately, if you still want to return array of std::strings, you can but only if you promise me that you will delete[] the returned pointer accordingly:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
std::string* F1()
{
    std::string* s=new std::string[2];
    s[0]="Hello";
    s[1]="World";
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string* ss=F1();
    std::cout<<ss[0]<<ss[1];

    delete[] ss; //important step
}
```

Comment: Best compile without exceptions, since otherwise you leak memory if anything throws...

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must return an array, you can use the fact that raw arrays decay into pointers.  Here's some sample code that does what I think you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

std::string * decode()
{
    std::string *ret = new std::string[2];
    ret[0] = "foo";
    ret[1] = "bar";
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::string *baz = decode();
    std::cout << baz[0] << baz[1] << std::endl;
    delete [] baz;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that this way requires you to keep track of the following:

- who owns the memory returned by `decode()`
- the fact that the pointer returned is really an array
- the size of the array

Yes, it's painful.  That's why everyone else has suggested using a `std::pair` or `std::vector` to handle the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the strings to the functions as "out" parameters - either by pointers or references and modify them within the function.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't actually recommend doing it this way for this specific case, but you can return a *reference* to an array of strings:

```
std::string(& split_once(std::string arg))[]
    static std::string result[2];
    int i = arg.find_first_of('|');
    result[0] = arg.substr(0,i);
    result[1] = arg.substr(i + 1);
}
```

This isn't well-suited for this particular application, but it *is* a valid way to return an array, and is useful in other situations. I think I've even used it somewhere, though I can't quite remember where or why.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

Return a `std::vector<std::string>`, return a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`, return a struct with the strings or, do not return, pass a reference and set it:

```
void decode(std::string & s1, std::string & s2, const std::string & otherParam) {
    // write the result to s1 and s2
}
```

With reference you will prevent an unnecessary copy.